# Which parameters of welch do determin the length of the output? (python)

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I am using welch in python.
Which parameter in welch does define the length of the output array?
Based on my trials, the output length is related to nperseg/2; but I cannot understand its reason and mathematics. And, I am not sure about the effect of other parameters on the output length.

Also, there is not enough explanation in its documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html)

I will be more than happy if anyone can help me. I could not find any clear info on the web!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the sentence from the documents

> Welch’s method [1] computes an estimate of the power spectral density by dividing the data into overlapping segments, computing a modified periodogram for each segment and averaging the periodograms.

```
def periodogram(x, Ts=1.0):
  '''
    This function will compute one score for each period 
    in 
  '''
  return abs(np.fft.rfft(x))**2
```

Then they say that the data is divided in overlapped segments and then added, so it is something like this

```
def welsh(data, nperseg, noverlap, window):
  stride = nperseg - noverlap
  return sum(periodogram(data[i*stride:i*stride+nperseg])
    for i in range((len(data) - nperseg) // stride))
```

i.e. you take segments of length nperseg to compute the periodograms, since you can get the periodogram only up to the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), you end up having `nperseg/2` (for nperseg).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Some points are not clear for me. The out-put of  "periodogram"  is an array, named P.  I thought that length of P is not related to nperseg while we transfer the data of each nperseg into frequency domain.

Comment: Anyway, How can I have a long length of output (I mean big value of nperseg), while I want to have fft results of small ranges (thus I can see the dynamics of the signal)?

Comment: Long signals can only improve the detection of long periods, i.e. short frequencies. Fast variations on low frequencies are not detectable. If you have heard about uncertainty principle in quantum mechanics, this is related. You may be looking for [Constant Q Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform) that try to get fast dynamics for high frequencies while keeping the resolution for low frequencies.

Comment: Many thanks, Bob. Is there a paper or reference that describes proper settings for Welch? For example, it explains how to find the best value of nperseg, fft and so on for a dataset. Again, thank you very much. You help me a lot.

Comment: Note also that the output can also be affected by the parameter `nfft` which can be used to get more output frequency points (equivalent to frequency interpolation, it does not produce a higher resolution output). @ReihanehKouhi about "how to find the best value of [...]": you'd have to define what's 'best' for you. It usually depends on what you're trying to achieve. Most of the time you'll want to use the smallest `nperseg` that achieves your required frequency resolution.